# Pure CSS menu generator

Tags: css, menu, software

I've been looking for hours for pure css, no js, menu creation software. All that I've found have either used js or did not have drop-down sub-menus. I have found one, but it's quite pricey for me and does more than I really need (although I do like it): css3menu.com

Does anyone know of a good one?

Thanks
Sean Gordon

Comment: Could you expand upon your desired features?

Comment: I would like to be able to make basic menus that use only HTML and CSS, no JS. Ability to save the project for future editing. Basic themes (images not needed). Horizontal and vertical menus. Sub-menus (more than one level preferably).

Comment: @SGWebsNow Trying to get a sense of context here: Is this for professional use? (Since you seem to need multiple projects, etc.) And £30-40 is quite pricey? To be fair, you're asking for quite a lot, and maybe you'd do better looking for a tutorial on building these yourself. It's really not terribly complicated, especially if you're not concerned about supporting IE6, which will almost definitely require a tiny bit of Javascript no matter what to do hover detection.

Comment: Son of Suckerfish Dropdowns is a popular DIY technique to build a menu with just HTML & CSS & very little JS (for IE6) - http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Comment: @Su http://purecssmenu.com/ is free, contains no js and works with IE6. It does, however, lack the ability to save project files.

Comment: @SGWebsNow The more important part of my question is whether this is for professional use, and the fact you provided an example that is frankly *not* all that pricey for your extensive requirements list.

Comment: I don't consider my requirements to be that extensive, so it seems expensive to me. This is for professional use, but I want something my client can use to update the website themselves at a later point.

Comment: @SGWebsNow - Standard CSS menus should only have `<li>` tags in their markup, so if your clients need to update the links, they simply need to change that list. If your clients are looking to do more, or aren't able to do that, then you might want to consider rolling a light-weight CMS.

Answer (score 2):

There are loads of them on Dynamic Drive - [horizontal](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/category/C1/) and [vertical](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/category/C2/).

You can use them in any end-user project, but not resell or redistribute them.

Comment: All of the drop-down ones use javascript.

Comment: Oh strange - I'm sure they used to do CSS only ones. Try Stu Nicholls instead then - http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/

Answer (score 1):

I actually use AllWebMenus which works fine for me and I think that it is fine for what you are looking for..It can make all the types of menus that you can imagine and I find its price really advantageous..You can always visit its site to check if it has the feature that you want..it's [Likno](http://www.likno.com)

I hope this helps!